# Error in IIS after changing some permission settings

Tags: iis

I got this error after changing some settings on ISS:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

I have checked and verified the folder of storing the web app:

```
TrustedInstaller - Full control
SYSTEM - Full control
Administrators - Full control
Users - Read & execute
CREATOR OWNER - Special
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends. What is you IIS version? What authentication methods are enabeld?

Comment: I used: IIS 7.5 and authenticationMode=Forms

Comment: Try assigning read rights for windows user group iis_iusrs to the folder. Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW: are you redirected to your login page when starting your application or does it fail immedeatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer for this:

Here's the steps to return to the default permissions for the wwwroot folder:

First, right-click on the wwwroot folder and click properties. Goto the Security tab and click the Advanced button. Click the Change Permissions... button and make check the "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" checkbox. Remove all permission entries where the "Inherited From" column has a value of "". Click apply and verify that the following 5 permission entries are being inherited from the "C:\inetpub\" directory:

```
TrustedInstaller - Full control
SYSTEM - Full control
Administrators - Full control
Users - Read & execute
CREATOR OWNER - Special
```

Once those permissions are verified, click the Add button and enter "IIS_IUSRS" for the object name and click OK. Select "Traverse folder / execute file", "List folder / read data", "Read attributes", "Read extended attributes", and "Read permissions" from the permissions list and click OK.

The wwwroot folder should now be set back to the out of the box permissions that come with IIS7.

This fixed the mentioned 401 Access Denied error I was encountering.